# How do I make an <input type=range> with restricted range?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, input

Consider the following range inputs put together with Flash:

[image: Range inputs with restricted ranges]

The grayed out areas on the edges of these inputs prevent the slider from reaching those ranges. And these ranges are dynamic, changing based on user input.

How would you put something like this together in HTML/JavaScript? Has anyone done anything similar to this in HTML, or can recommend a library that can handle this?

I'm putting together my application with React, but I can adapt any HTML/JavaScript to my system to accommodate this.

Comment: What's wrong with the `min` and `max` attributes?

Comment: I don't think there is this grayed out areas feature built in to the browser API just min and max.

Comment: min and max attributes don't visually illustrate the restricted range to the user. So, I may have to go with those to start, but it's not ideal. I know this isn't built into the HTML input spec - I'm asking for recommendations for anyone who has made something like this in JavaScript.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it's requesting code or library recommendations. Working with react, it shouldn't be too hard to build a slider component with that feature set with a little bit of effort. Should you encounter any specific problems as per the StackOverflow guidelines, post a MCVE so we can help.